# Parsing a json (a response from freebase) in python

Tags: python, json, freebase

Parsing a json (a response from freebase) in python
This question is regarding `JSON` parsing. I am querying freebase for some data and getting a `JSON` object. The response has a following structure

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "attribute0": [
        "attrbVal0"
      ],
      "attribute1": [],
      "attribute2": "attrbVal1",
      "attribute3": [
        "val1",
        "val2"
      ],
      "creator": "abc",
      "key": [
        "val2",
        "val3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that, the attributes can have zero values to any number of values. When there are no values it is represented as [] or null.
The set of attributes is not known to me. It changes as the query changes,So I can't hard code the values like

```
result['attribute2'];
```

From the above `JSON` I want to get the attributes where the value is either `[]` or `null`.
I have tried following things to get attributes and values,

```
print response.keys()
```

prints result

```
for r in response['result']: 
    print r
```

This prints everything inside result in one go. That is

```
print len(result) #prints 1
```

I have tried the following to get the list of attributes, but no luck.

```
result = response['result']
elem = json.loads(result);
keys = elem.keys()
```

So I am looking for the code to get all key value pairs from the above json and some explanation pointing out my mistake.

Comment: `response["result"]` is a list of dictionaries (in your case, with a single dictionary).

Comment: I've reformatted your JSON according to its actual nested structure, which should make your error clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the *items* of a dictionary, giving you both the keys and the values in pairs; this then lets you filter on the value:

```
for result in response['result']:
    for attrname, value in result.items():
        if not value:  # empty list or None
            print attrname
```

Note that `response['result']` is a list, containing (presumably) one or more dictionary objects.

In Python both the empty list and `None` (the Python equivalent of the JSON `null`) are considered false in a boolean context, so `not value` is `True` for those attributes whose values are either an empty list or `null` in the original JSON response.

Demo:

```
>>> response = {
...   "result": [
...     {
...       "attribute0": [
...         "attrbVal0"
...       ],
...       "attribute1": [],
...       "attribute2": "attrbVal1",
...       "attribute3": [
...         "val1",
...         "val2"
...       ],
...       "creator": "abc",
...       "key": [
...         "val2",
...         "val3"
...       ]
...     }
...   ]
... }
>>> for result in response['result']:
...     for attrname, value in result.items():
...         if not value:  # empty list or None
...             print attrname
... 
attribute1
```

So in your sample input, only `attribute1` has an empty value.

Comment: Your assumption of `len(response)` = 1 is correct and `type(response)` is `dict`. I am getting the following error. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: @Hegde: ah, I missed the fact that `response['result']` is a list, not a single dictionary. Updated.

Comment: That is working very well. Thank you @Martin Pieters